# What is the maximum size for SegWit transactions?

Tags: segregated-witness, block-weight, transaction-weight

Before SegWit was activated, transactions were limited to 100,000 bytes or 100 kB. Bigger transactions were non-standard.

What is the limit for transaction size after the activation of SegWit?

- Is the virtual size limited to 100,000 vbytes?
- Is the raw size limited to 100,000 bytes?
- Is there a new limit altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standardness limit in all recent Bitcoin Core versions with SegWit support is 400000 weight.